# Suspend/resume painting of treeview's scrollbars

Tags: c#, treeview, repaint, scrollbars, redraw

I am trying to stop a treeview's vertical scrollbar from flickering when redrawing the treeview. I already have a custom treeview control which can disable painting using WndProc, and it works fine for the treeview itself but won't stop the treeview's scrollbars from re-painting and flickering whenever I clear/create the nodes in the treeview.

Is there any solution to this? Here is the code from the custom treeview:

```
    private bool enablePaint = true;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
                if (enablePaint)
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
            case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution, using LockWindowUpdate:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr hWndLock);
    public new void BeginUpdate()
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)0, IntPtr.Zero);
        LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
    }
    public new void EndUpdate()
    {
        LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout use LockWindowUpdate "behind the scenes". I could be wrong though.

Comment: I tried those, ie. replaced the LockWindowUpdates with them, but the vertical scrollbar flickers. LWU is the only solution I've found that works.